# Ableton Live 9 missing resources

Tags: ableton-live

I am using Ableton Live 9 on my macbook air but it is running frm an external hard drive. Whenever I try to put certain sounds onto a track I am creating the program gives me an error that the media files are missing. Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem may be?

Comment: Did you delete the media files on accident? Is it a fresh install?

Answer (score 3):

You can force Live to search your computer for the media files

Click the orange Status Bar to bring up the File Manager View.
Here you can set Live to automatically search for the missing files.